# Respect @Lazy annotation on non-@Primary @Bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm having problems getting Spring to respect the `@Lazy` annotation on `@Bean` methods when it is configured to use a different `@Bean` method that returns an implementation of the same interface that is flagged as `@Primary`.

Specifically, I have a `@Configuration`-annotated class with several `@Bean` methods that all return the same interface. Many of these `@Bean` methods are `@Lazy`, as they contact external services for which the application may not currently be using. The `@Primary` bean is not `@Lazy`, as it looks at runtime configuration to determine which implementation to return.

Here is a contrived example of that configuration class, revolving around a fictitious `ThingService` interface:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.things" })
public class ThingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ThingOptions thingOptions() {
        ThingOptions options = new ThingOptions();
        options.sharing = true;
        return options;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ThingService primaryThing(ThingOptions options, ApplicationContext context) {
        System.out.println("PrimaryThing -- Initialized");

        if (options.sharing) {
            return context.getBean("OurThing", ThingService.class);
        } else {
            return context.getBean("YourThing", ThingService.class);
        }
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "YourThing")
    public ThingService yourThing() {
        System.out.println("YourThingService -- Initialized");
        return new YourThingService();
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = "OurThing")
    public ThingService ourThing() {
        System.out.println("OurThingService -- Initialized");
        return new OurThingService();
    }

}
```

I then have a `@Component` that depends on this interface which that the `@Primary` annotation will ensure that the correct implementation will be injected into the object. Here is an example of that downstream `@Component`:

```java
@Component
public class ThingComponent {

    private final ThingService thingService;

    @Inject
    public ThingComponent(ThingService thingService) {
        this.thingService = thingService;
    }

}
```

I then built a small test to ensure that `@Lazy` and `@Primary` are all being respected.

```java
public class ThingTest {

    @Test
    public void TestLazyAndPrimary() {

        // Arrange

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(ThingConfiguration.class);
        context.refresh();

        // Act

        ThingComponent component = context.getBean(ThingComponent.class);

        // Assert

        Assert.assertNotNull(component);
    }

}
```

However, when I run this test, I found that `@Lazy` was being ignored. The following text is emitted to the console:

```sh
PrimaryThing -- Initialized
OurThingService -- Initialized
YourThingService -- Initialized
```

The `"YourThing"` `@Bean` should not have been initialized, as it was `@Lazy` and not loaded at runtime via the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method. Yet when the `ThingComponent` is resolved, it causes the `@Bean` methods with that return an implementation of `ThingService` to be hydrated before the `@Primary` mean is chosen.

**How do I get the `@Primary` annotated implementation of an interface to be respected without causing all of the non-`@Primary` implementations annotated with `@Lazy` to be hydrated?**

Comment: You could make use of the different conditional annotations, though I am not entirely sure if its a spring-boot only thing

Comment: Thanks @Lino. Any recommendations on specific annotations I should look at as alternatives to this pattern?

Comment: I'm sadly on mobile but this is a doc from spring I've found, it should explain how to use the annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know that existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to stop the `@Primary` annotation from forcing eager hydration of all `@Bean` methods that return that interface, even though this information seems available without forcing hydration from the annotations in exclusivity. I got around this by using a naming convention on `@Bean` methods instead.

Specifically, I changed my `@Primary` annotated `@Bean` method to include a `name` like so:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.things" })
public class ThingConfiguration {

    // @Primary -- I don't want someone to accidentally use this without a @Qualifier!
    @Bean(name = "PrimaryThingService")
    public ThingService primaryThing(ThingOptions options, ApplicationContext context) {
        System.out.println("PrimaryThing -- Initialized");

        if (options.sharing) {
            return context.getBean("OurThing", ThingService.class);
        } else {
            return context.getBean("YourThing", ThingService.class);
        }
    }

    // ... the rest of the methods removed for clarity ...

}
```

Then I placed a `@Qualifier` on the `ThingService` being injected into the `@Component` like so:

```java
@Component
public class ThingComponent {

    private final ThingService thingService;

    @Inject
    public ThingComponent(@Qualifier("PrimaryThingService") ThingService thingService) {
        this.thingService = thingService;
    }

}
```

Now when I rerun the test, I get the following output:

```
PrimaryThing -- Initialized
OurThingService -- Initialized
```

So this removes the `@Primary` annotation in place of using a named `@Bean` following a convention of `"Primary{Interface}"`, stepping around the Spring's overeager hydration of non-`@Primary` annotated `@Bean` methods.